Apache Drill won't load because of a space in the path for Java?
I'm trying to get started with Apache Drill and following the 10 minute tutorial.
When I run bin/drill-embedded I get the following error:

/Users/breuds/Desktop/Drill/apache-drill-1.21.1/bin/sqlline: line 95: /Library/Internet: No such file or directory
/Users/breuds/Desktop/Drill/apache-drill-1.21.1/bin/sqlline: line 95: exec: /Library/Internet: cannot execute: No such file or directory

When I run /usr/libexec/java_home -V I only have one instance of Java:

Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
1.8.411.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

But I noticed something odd: my Java references "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/.." and my error references "/Library/Internet".
Is that space throwing off Drill?
How do I adjust for it?
MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1

It looks like you're right, but people do use Drill on OS X so there must be a way around. Does this answer help?
